# How to change color of separator on Breadcrumbs

Tags: next.js, breadcrumbs

```
<Breadcrumbs separator="›" aria-label="breadcrumb">
    <Link href="/recipes/" >
        recipes
    </Link>
    <Link href='/recipes/bread/'  >
        bread
    </Link>
    <Link href='/recipes/bread/quickbrad'  >
        quick bread
    </Link>
</Breadcrumbs>
```

I what to change the color of the separator to red. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

In inspect you have on  Breadcrumbs `li` element that is hidden and you have class `MuiBreadcrumbs-separator` and that class you can put on global style, and style like this let's say:

```
.MuiBreadcrumbs-separator{
  color: red;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In the CSS add:

```
.breadcrumb:before {
    color: //your_color;
 }
```

Comment: import StyleBreadcrumbs from '../styles/Breadcrumbs.module.css'

Comment: <Breadcrumbs className={StyleBreadcrumbs.breadcrumb} LIke this?